# How to avoid Duration from pop up in gantt chart Google chart

Tags: google-visualization

I have a Google Gantt chart and I need to avoid duration because in my start date and end date I need to remove some days.

How can I avoid duration from pop up in the Gantt chart?

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['gantt'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(draw_Charts);
        function draw_Charts() {
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/web_service/Chart.asmx/Char,
                datadata: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
                    dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Name');
                    dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Resources');
                    dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Start');
                    dataTable.addColumn('date', 'End');
                    dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
                    dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
                    dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');


                    for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
                        var Task_ID = response.d[i][1];
                        var name = response.d[i][1];
                        var Resources = null;
                        var start = new Date(response.d[i][2].toString());
                        var end = new Date(response.d[i][3].toString());
                        var Duration = null;
                        var Percent = null;
                        var Dependencies = null;
                        dataTable.addRows([[Task_ID, name, Resources, start, end, Duration, Percent, Dependencies]]);
                    }
                    var paddingHeight = 30;
                    var rowHeight = dataTable.getNumberOfRows() * 35;
                    var chartHeight = rowHeight + paddingHeight;
                    var options = {
                        width: "100%",
                        height: chartHeight,
                        gantt: {
                            trackHeight: 30, // Critical path arrows will be the same as other arrows.

                            arrow: {
                                angle: 100,
                                width: 5,
                                color: 'green',
                                radius: 0
                            },
                            barCornerRadius: 2,
                            backgroundColor: {
                                fill: 'transparent',
                            },
                            shadowOffset: 2,
                            palette: [
                                {
                                    "color": "#ff5d00",
                                    "dark": "#FCD6B6",
                                    "light": "#eeeeee"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    };
                    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
                    var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(container);
                    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
                },
                failure: function (r) {
                    alert(r.status + " - " + r.statusText);
                },
                error: function (r) {
                    alert(r.status + " - " + r.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: duration is not required -- see [computing start / end / duration](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#computing-startendduration)

Comment: @WhiteHat thank you. but when i removed (duration column)from my chart she give me error

Comment: use `null` as the value for the duration column -- [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41449314/5090771)...

Comment: @WhiteHat is not working with null automatically count duration :(

Comment: not sure I follow, will you please clarify?

Comment: so after reading again, it sounds like you want to remove the duration from the tooltip that displays when you hover a bar on the chart? is that correct?

Comment: @WhiteHat yes correct.

Comment: @WhiteHat yes that's what i want.  :)

Comment: sure, I'll take a look when I get a chance...

Comment: to my knowledge, there are no standard options you can use to change the tooltip on the Gantt chart. you could try removing the duration row from the tooltip when it pops up, but this will be difficult. you can identify when the tooltip appears using a `MutationObserver`...